# In React Native, my console.log functions but my <div> write nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display a map function, the console.log functions into my map but nothing is displayed on my screen.

There is my map :

```
    const myMap = () => {

      followers.map((followers) =>{
        console.log(followers.login)

        return (
          <view>
        <h1>
        {followers.login}
        aaa
        {console.log(followers.login)}
        {console.log("----------------------")}
        </h1>
          </view>
           
        );
      });  
    }
```

the console.log gives the correct answer.

there is my return (look at in the modal):

```
 return (
            <View>
              <Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType='slide'>
                {modalselector == "followers"?
                <View>
                <MaterialIcons
                name='close'
                style={styles.modalToggle}
                size={24}
                onPress={() => setModalOpen(false)}
                />

                <Text>
                  hello
                  {myMap()}

                </Text>
                
              </View>: null }
                 </Modal>
```

the hello is displayed, in myMap all the console.logs are working but nothing got displayed.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `myMap` doesn't return anything, it is missing a return statement like `return followers.map(...`

Comment: you are right, but i don't understand, i can return in a return?

Comment: No, It's another scope and function. The innermost `return` is from the anonymous function you are passing to `followers.map()` and not from `myMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your myMap component is not rendering anything because it is not returning anything, here is a simple code that works. By the way your component should start with an uppercase letter and you cannot use the same variable name 'followers' inside the followers.map

```
const MyMap = ({ followers }) => {
// Here is the missing return
return (
    <>
        {followers.map(follower => {
            return (
                <view>
                    <h1>{follower}</h1>
                </view>
            )
        })}
    </>
)}
```